# Acceleration of Internet Connection on Windows 10 by using multiple network adapters?

Tags: networking, windows-10

Is there a way to do this?

I have these connections at the moment:

- Ethernet (ThinkPad T410 Built in)
- Wi-Fi (2.4ghz T410 Built in)
- Linksys Wireless-B USB Adapter (WUSB11v3)
- Linksys Wireless-B USB Adapter (WUSB11v2, yes I have two)

(if I need a third party app first, I don't mind)

NOTE: I want to do this B/C my WiFi card is crap and my Ethernet card is crap.

Comment: How fast is theInternet speed coming from your ISP? Is it faster than 1Gbit? If not just use the wired Ethernet for maximum speed and reliability.

Comment: Wireless-B is too old and will create congestion to your own WiFi network and that of your neighbors.

There are ways to aggregate multiple links (LACP for 2 Ethernet cards) but you might find most of them impractical, this usually only done for local file sharing and not Internet Speed.

Comment: @Hennes I know, but that doesn't help.

Comment: @cloneman ok but still